# How to get html file name directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ZF and I need to get the current phtml file using JS. however I'm using routes so I can't get the file name from the URL.Any Idea how to do that??

---

ex:
I hava a template name example.phtml
I'm using it in 
domain.com/home

how to get example.phtml

Comment: please modify your question, as you are not clear.

Comment: If you don't specify the name of template explicitly - it equals to the action name.

Comment: @zerkms the template name differs from the action name.. and I'm using multiple templates in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this.

HTTP clients deal only in URLs and whatever arbitrary data that people want to put in HTTP headers and bodies.

The files that the server touches in order to generate a response are hidden from the client (except, perhaps, by implication which you've said is not the case here).

If you want to tell the client about `example.phtml` (which probably isn't a great way to deal with whatever your actual problem is) then you'll need to put that information in the arbitrary data (e.g. in the response body).